# jquery making local variable in function global

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function that populates the currsong variable with data.
The problem is that the variable currsong is only available inside the function and I need to access it globally.

```
// get a single audio url
echonest.artist(artist).audio( function(audioCollection) {
    var currsong = audioCollection.data.audio[0].url;
    return currsong;
    });
```

Thank you!

Comment: There is no question here... there is simply a vague statement, and a block of code.  This is the perfect example of a poorly structure question.

Comment: Can you please share the code you are using to call this function.

Comment: Here you go fudgey http://jsfiddle.net/2sCSC/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To declare a global variable, you can always remove `var`:

```
currsong = audioCollection.data.audio[0].url;
```

I'm not sure if a global variable is a good solution for whatever you're trying to do, though. People suggest to avoid them for reason.

**edit**
[An example](http://jsfiddle.net/qbYTQ/).
Note, the variable will be undefined before function is executed first time. In your code, you only pass it into `audio`, you don't actually invoke it.

**edit2**
As **Tgr** notes, you can also declare global variable *explicitly*: `window.currsong = ...`. There's no functional difference, but it improves code quality.

Comment: You could do that, but I'm not convinced that using a global variable is the best way of solving this problem.

Comment: @quanticle We weren't asked "how to solve this problem", we've been asked "how to declare this variable global". I would also like to suggest better solution, yet OP didn't describe his problem for that.

Comment: I concede the point regarding what we were asked. Regardless, I maintain that if adding a global variable is your first resort, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @quanticle Then say that to OP, maybe you'll convince him :)  I myself already put a warning in the post.

Comment: `window.currsong` would be preferable, as it makes it obvious that 1) currsong is global, 2) it is intentionally global. Omitting a var is an easy mistake, as is not noticing that it is not there. Tools like jslint will even consider implied globals as errors, and they are forbidden in strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

Scope is an interesting bird in javascript.  So is closure.

Observation 1: you are returning a value from an inline function; that return value is meaningless.

Observation 2: by using the "var" keyword, you are specifying a local scope.  Removing var will make the variable global.  However, even if you do that it is possible that you will attempt to access that variable before the function gets triggered (i.e. it will be undefined).

Since you're just starting to wrap your head around the concept of closure and javascript scope, I'd recommend reading up on it and then rethinking your application design (since I would be willing to bet that you will learn something which prompts another approach).

In the mean time, try defining the variable outside of the inline function and giving it a temporary value.  After that remove "var" from inside of the function.

```
// get a single audio url
var currsong = "temporary value";
echonest.artist(artist).audio( function(audioCollection) {
    currsong = audioCollection.data.audio[0].url;
    return currsong;
});
```

Comment: thank you slifty, i tried that and it does come back undefined. i appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten your code to make it a little more clear for myself and others. Please let me know if I've transliterated something incorrectly.

Basically, it looks like you're trying to get curSong as follows:

```
echonest.artist(artist).audio(
    function(audioCollection){
        var curSong = audioCollection.data.audio[0].url;
        return curSong;
    }
);
```

Right now, what you're doing is passing a function (the anonymous function defined by `function(audioCollection)`) to the `audio` function of whatever `artist(artist)` returns. As such, the `curSong` value is returned to `audio()`, and then only when `audio()` actually runs the function that its handed. I would look at `audio()` and try to see if there is a way to get `curSong` out of it.  Otherwise, I'd do as slifty describes above and declare `curSong` in a larger scope, so that it can be accessed even outside of `audio()`.

**EDIT**: For example, a sample audio function could be as follows:

```
function audio(inputFunction){
    var audioCollection = getAudioCollection();
    var song = inputFunction(audioCollection);
    return song;
}
```

The variable `curSong` is in an anonymous function being passed to `audio()`. As such, it doesn't *exist* until that anonymous function is executed, as in the above code. Now, when you run your code (from the first snippet), the anonymous inner function will return `curSong` to `audio()`, and `audio()` will return `curSong` to you.

Comment: thank you for that quanticle. basically the curSong var is unavailable from outside the function even without the var in front. I have no idea how to access it from another function

Comment: `audio()` should have access to `curSong`, as the function is returning `curSong`.